# Where should I put "-ly" in the sentence to make it look natural?

Tags: adverbs

I want to put the word which is ended 'ly' like 'resolutely', 'emphatically'. Which place is right?
End of the sentence or between 'she' and 'objects'?

1. She objects to the proposals.
2. They remain opposed to the idea.

Comment: This does sound like you're asking us to do your English homework for you - I don't think you've just got a burning desire to use an adverb. Have you done any research? There are countless articles online about adverb placement.

Comment: You can google "abverb placement", the explanation may be more detailed than you can get here.

Comment: I will do more research with burning desire next time. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These words are **adverbs** - they modify the verb, and are usually placed before or after it.

> She objects strongly to the proposals

is probably the most natural, but you could say

> She strongly objects to the proposals.

In the case of sentence (2), it's really the opposition rather than the remaining that is being emphasised, so I would suggest

> They remain resolutely opposed to the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!